# Sending serial data without RS232 port

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I want to send data serially from MATLAB, but my laptop doesn't have a serial port. Do I have to use a USB-to-RS232 converter? Will my program remain the same?

Answer (score 1):

I have some RS232-USB-Converters and never had any trouble. I need adapters for embedded devices and embedded development.

If your driver is properly installed and works then it is presented as an serial device to the OS.

The device presented (on linux) is named differently (ttyUSB) but that doesn't matter.
And using stdio functions like fopen/fclose is one more layer above (libcall, not syscall).